# Are some of the Standards fields on Contact accessible only via API or SOQL or Reports?

Tags: contact, standard-field

When you go to Setup > Object Manager > Contact > Fields and Relationships, the following Standard Contact Fields are not available. As a result, these cannot be added to page layouts.

Last Activity Date,
Last Referenced Date,
Last Viewed Date,
Photo URL

However, Last Referenced Date is available in Reports.

Are these fields available only via SOQL and API and may be Reports ?

Comment: they are in the [Contact schema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm?q=contact)

Comment: You've identified some fields, but what exactly is your question here?

Comment: My question is -  Last Referenced Date, Last Viewed Date and Photo URL - are these fields available only via SOQL and API

Comment: @cropredy I have edited my question.  My question was misunderstood.

Comment: a cursory check shows that these fields are not available on reports, including custom report types but others may have a better answer; this is worth asking on the [Trailblazer Community Feed](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed?tab=following)